Misaligned sf object in ggplot
I have two sf objects, which when plotting are slightly misaligned.
While initially the two objects have different CRS:

the first has: WGS 84
the second has: MGI / Austria GK East

I proceed, as usual with:
sf2 <- st_transform(sf2, crs = st_crs(sf1))
to align the CRS. However still, when plotting this:
ggplot() 
  + geom_sf(sf1)
  + geom_sf(sf2, color = "green", fill = "transparent")       

I get the attached output. Any ideas what I am doing wrong? 
Datasources are:
sf1: https://data.wien.gv.at/daten/geo?service=WFS&request=GetFeature&version=1.1.0&typeName=ogdwien:BEZIRKSGRENZEOGD&srsName=EPSG:31256&outputFormat=shape-zip
sf2: https://data.wien.gv.at/daten/geo?service=WFS&request=GetFeature&version=1.1.0&typeName=ogdwien:ZAEHLBEZIRKOGD&srsName=EPSG:4326&outputFormat=shape-zip

Likely red herring, but set  sf_use_s2(FALSE) prior to st_transform.

Where/how did you source your data? Some example data will be helpful here. Subset sf1 and sf2 to only the single most northwestern polygon, run dput() on both subsets, and add the results to a codeblock in your question. The results will look something like structure(list(...)).

Links to the source/s of your data will also be useful in order to rule out any processing errors you may have accidentally made e.g. the data may have already been corrupted.

many thanks for the comments: I found a "workaround" when exporting a subsample (see Answer). I however still do not understand the problem.
I have updated the question by adding the data sources. I couldn't however attach the dput() output, as it was too long.

The "solution" to the problem was, that:

I export the misplaced sf2 as gpkg
st_write(sf2, dsn = "sf2.gpkg") 
and import it again
sf2 <- st_read("sf2.gpkg")

all of a sudden the polygons align, even though running
identical(st_crs(sf1), st_crs(sf2))gives me FALSE
I still do not understand the issue - but it worked.


Your "solution" still gives the wrong map, as in your question, for me.
